How can a string like "Null" be cast to a null value?
I'm baffled by this bug in the FAFSA website (reported by the WSJ):

In October, officials resolved an issue that was preventing applicants from inviting contributors with the last name of “Null” (computer speak for zero), which blocked submission.

This sounds like a 1980s joke. I can't even how to imagine how to produce that effect, even in the weakly typed languages I know. Can anyone explain a 21st century programming practice that could produce this behavior?
The most plausible scenario I can imagine would be inserting a string directly into a SQL query string, without quotes. But surely that would also cause errors for people whose last names have spaces.
(Bonus points as well if someone knows what languages the FAFSA site uses, though I couldn't find that online.)

"This sounds like a 1980s joke" - it very well might be, the FAFSA has been around since 1965 - not unthinkable that the current database schema builds on a design that predates most modern database engines :)

It also might be some programmer thinking he's smart and adding a if statement to "catch edge cases" and inadvertently causing this bug.  Maybe "Null" was used as a placeholder value in HTTP requests and it happened to conflict with other things

It's not too uncommon for sloppily-written applications to contain questionable logic like if ((lastName == null) or (lastName.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))) ThrowNullValueException();

In many languages, strings are not reference types and therefore cannot be null. So you have to come up with some other way to represent null.
